# Moving map markers in GMap.NET

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I haven't found anything on how to change position of placed `GMap.NET` markers. I need to be able to move it through GUI by mouse (drag and drop) and/or manually by entering new coordinates. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar, with arrow key buttons moving a plane marker. The GMapMarker class has a position variable you can use for this. Using my code as an example, it looks something like this:

plane.Position = new PointLatLng(latitude, longitude)